# Unable to fill the polygon with a color

Tags: android, polygon, google-maps-android-api-2

I am adding a Polygon like this:

```
PolygonOptions options = new PolygonOptions();
for (int x = 0; x <= 360; x++) {

//get LatLng ll
options.add(ll);
}
options.strokeColor(Color.BLUE);
options.strokeWidth(2);
options.fillColor(Color.CYAN);
map.addPolygon(options);
```

What i get is a blue stroke polygon(circle). But I am not able to fill it with a color(it just empty). What am i missing?

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the vertices are added in counterclockwise order as given in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/PolygonOptions?hl=es#addAll%28java.lang.Iterable%3Ccom.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng%3E%29).

Comment: I didn't look much into it. But since my for loop goes from **0 to 360** it should be counter clock-wise?

Comment: I am not sure, just try with running the loop in the reverse order and check!

Comment: Yep. You are right, reversing the loop worked. Thanks a lot bro.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Docs](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/Markers,-Lines-and-Polygons-(Java)), to fill the polygon with color, the vertices should be added in clockwise order. If you want to make holes, they should be added in counter-clockwise order

```
    List<GeoPoint> geoPoints = new ArrayList<>();
    //clockwise
    geoPoints.add(new GeoPoint(-8.146242825034385, -29.267578125));
    geoPoints.add(new GeoPoint(-12.8974891, -25.3125));
    geoPoints.add(new GeoPoint(-23.40276490, -33.585937499999));
    geoPoints.add(new GeoPoint(-17.895114303, -40.51757812));
    Polygon polygon = new Polygon();    //see note below
    geoPoints.add(geoPoints.get(0));    //forces the loop to close(connect last point to first point)
    polygon.getFillPaint().setColor(Color.RED); //set fill color,

    polygon.setPoints(geoPoints);

    //polygons supports holes too, points should be in a counter-clockwise order
    // List<List<GeoPoint>> holes = new ArrayList<>();
    // holes.add(geoPoints); //HERE geopoints has to be a different list from above
    // polygon.setHoles(holes);
```

Answer (score 0):

if duplicate points exits in list then also fill color will be not shown.
actually I'm adding same point list two time into polygon's point list that the issue in my case

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).